# How do I move my boxes from behind below the dimond DIV?

Tags: html, css

I'm learning HTML5 and CSS but having this error that the divs are presented behind other div. I am trying to separate diamonds with the boxes to show below and when clicked on the diamonds it will jump to that part of the page (which I am still working on, no need for help there).

Can someone help me please been on this for hours. I am trying to show the rectangle boxes below the diamonds, I know there is something wrong with the CSS part but cant find the error help will be appreciated thank you.

```css
/*layout of body page*/
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background-color: #000;
    font-family: poppins, sans-serif;
}

/*dimonds cover page top*/
.main-nav{
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    width:600px;
    height:150px;
}

.main-nav li{
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    transform:rotate(45deg);
    transition: 0.5s;
    margin: -100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 0.6;
    border-color: rgb(236, 39, 236);
    border: solid rgb(236, 39, 236)
}

.main-nav li:hover{
    opacity: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/*about me button*/
.main-nav li.item1{
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    color: white;
    font-size: 47px;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1px #6531a8;
    text-shadow: 0px 2px 4px #8c31b6;
}

.main-nav li.item2{
    bottom: 0;
    left: 25%;
    color: white;
    font-size: 47px;
    
}

.main-nav li.item3{
    top:0;
    left: 50%;
    color: white;
    font-size: 47px;
}

.main-nav li.item4{
    top: 100%;
    left: 75%;
    color: white;
    font-size: 47px;
}

.main-nav li.item5{
    top: 0%;
    left: 100%;
    color: white;
    font-size: 47px;
    
}

.main-nav li.bg{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transform: scale(1.1);;
}

.title{
    background-color: rgb(192, 183, 183);
    top: 0;
    width: 75px;
    height: 0;
    margin: 70px;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: popping, sans-serif;
    font-size: x-large;
    font-weight: 700;
    position: relative;
    left: -40px;
}


.main-nav li.item1 .bg{
    background-size:cover;
    background-position: center;
}


.nav-title{
    border-radius: 25%;
    border: solid 2px rgb(236, 39, 236);
    height: 71%;
    width: 386px;
    align-content: center;
    color: white;
    display: inline;
}

.nav-title:nth-child(n + 2){
    margin-left: -1px;
}


/*border lines for dimonds bottom page */
#container{
    padding:5px;
    width:100%;
    height:500px;
}

.row{
    min-height:50px;
    margin-top:25px;
    width:90%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    padding:2%; 
}

.half-row{
    display:inline-block;
    width:50%;
    margin:1%;
    height:25%;
    color:white;
    border: 2px solid yellow;
    border-radius: 25px;
}

.textting{
  color:white;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Home Page Jump</title>
</head>

<body>




    <ul class="main-nav">
        <button onclick=""> <!--jump to first section box-->
            <!-- first is picked-->
            <li class="item1">
                <div class="bg">
                    <div class="title">
                        First
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </button>
        
        <!-- second button is clicked-->
        <button onclick=""> <!--jump to 2 section box-->
            <li class="item2">
                <div class="bg">
                    <div class="title">
                        Second
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </button>

        <!--Third box info is clicked-->
        <button onclick=""> <!--jump to first section box-->
            <li class="item3">
                <div class="bg">
                    <div class="title">
                        Third
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </button>

        <!--fourth div is cliked-->
        <button onclick=""> <!--jump to first section box-->
            <li class="item4">
                <div class="bg">
                    <div class="title">
                        Fourth
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </button>

        <!--firth is cliked -->
        <button onclick=""> <!--jump to first section box-->
            <li class="item5">
                <div class="bg">
                    <div class="title">
                        Fifth
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </button>
    </ul>


    <div id="container"> 
        <div class="row">
            <div class="half-row" style="width:15%;">
             <div class="textting">
               <h1>
                 First Info
               </h1>
             
             </div>
             
            </div>
            <div class="half-row">
              <h3>
                blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
                blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
              </h3>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row">
            <div class="half-row" style="width:15%;">
             <div class="textting">
               <h1>
                 Second Info
               </h1>
             
             </div>
             
            </div>
            <div class="half-row">
              <h3>
                blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
                blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
              </h3>
            </div>
        </div>




        <div class="row">
            <div class="half-row" style="width:15%;">
             <div class="textting">
               <h1>
                 Third Info
               </h1>
             
             </div>
             
            </div>
            <div class="half-row">
              <h3>
                blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
                blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
              </h3>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="half-row" style="width:15%;">
             <div class="textting">
               <h1>
                 Third Info
               </h1>
             
             </div>
             
            </div>
            <div class="half-row">
              <h3>
                blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
                blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
              </h3>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="half-row" style="width:15%;">
             <div class="textting">
               <h1>
                 Fourth Info
               </h1>
             
             </div>
             
            </div>
            <div class="half-row">
              <h3>
                blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
                blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
              </h3>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="half-row" style="width:15%;">
             <div class="textting">
               <h1>
                 Fifth Info
               </h1>
             
             </div>
             
            </div>
            <div class="half-row">
              <h3>
                blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
                blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
              </h3>
            </div>
        </div>



    </div>


</body>


<script>


</script>




</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add padding-top to #container css i.e padding-top:350px;

```css
/*layout of body page*/
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background-color: #000;
    font-family: poppins, sans-serif;
}

/*dimonds cover page top*/
.main-nav{
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    width:600px;
    height:150px;
}

.main-nav li{
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    transform:rotate(45deg);
    transition: 0.5s;
    margin: -100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 0.6;
    border-color: rgb(236, 39, 236);
    border: solid rgb(236, 39, 236)
}

.main-nav li:hover{
    opacity: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/*about me button*/
.main-nav li.item1{
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    color: white;
    font-size: 47px;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1px #6531a8;
    text-shadow: 0px 2px 4px #8c31b6;
}

.main-nav li.item2{
    bottom: 0;
    left: 25%;
    color: white;
    font-size: 47px;
    
}

.main-nav li.item3{
    top:0;
    left: 50%;
    color: white;
    font-size: 47px;
}

.main-nav li.item4{
    top: 100%;
    left: 75%;
    color: white;
    font-size: 47px;
}

.main-nav li.item5{
    top: 0%;
    left: 100%;
    color: white;
    font-size: 47px;
    
}

.main-nav li.bg{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transform: scale(1.1);;
}

.title{
    background-color: rgb(192, 183, 183);
    top: 0;
    width: 75px;
    height: 0;
    margin: 70px;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: popping, sans-serif;
    font-size: x-large;
    font-weight: 700;
    position: relative;
    left: -40px;
}


.main-nav li.item1 .bg{
    background-size:cover;
    background-position: center;
}


.nav-title{
    border-radius: 25%;
    border: solid 2px rgb(236, 39, 236);
    height: 71%;
    width: 386px;
    align-content: center;
    color: white;
    display: inline;
}

.nav-title:nth-child(n + 2){
    margin-left: -1px;
}


/*border lines for dimonds bottom page */
#container{
    padding:5px;
padding-top:350px; /*edit here*/
width:100%;
height:500px;
}

.row{
    min-height:50px;
    margin-top:25px;
    width:90%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    padding:2%; 
}

.half-row{
    display:inline-block;
    width:50%;
    margin:1%;
    height:25%;
    color:white;
    border: 2px solid yellow;
    border-radius: 25px;
}

.textting{
  color:white;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Home Page Jump</title>
</head>

<body>




    <ul class="main-nav">
        <button onclick=""> <!--jump to first section box-->
            <!-- first is picked-->
            <li class="item1">
                <div class="bg">
                    <div class="title">
                        First
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </button>
        
        <!-- second button is clicked-->
        <button onclick=""> <!--jump to 2 section box-->
            <li class="item2">
                <div class="bg">
                    <div class="title">
                        Second
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </button>

        <!--Third box info is clicked-->
        <button onclick=""> <!--jump to first section box-->
            <li class="item3">
                <div class="bg">
                    <div class="title">
                        Third
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </button>

        <!--fourth div is cliked-->
        <button onclick=""> <!--jump to first section box-->
            <li class="item4">
                <div class="bg">
                    <div class="title">
                        Fourth
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </button>

        <!--firth is cliked -->
        <button onclick=""> <!--jump to first section box-->
            <li class="item5">
                <div class="bg">
                    <div class="title">
                        Fifth
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </button>
    </ul>


    <div id="container"> 
        <div class="row">
            <div class="half-row" style="width:15%;">
             <div class="textting">
               <h1>
                 First Info
               </h1>
             
             </div>
             
            </div>
            <div class="half-row">
              <h3>
                blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
                blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
              </h3>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row">
            <div class="half-row" style="width:15%;">
             <div class="textting">
               <h1>
                 Second Info
               </h1>
             
             </div>
             
            </div>
            <div class="half-row">
              <h3>
                blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
                blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
              </h3>
            </div>
        </div>




        <div class="row">
            <div class="half-row" style="width:15%;">
             <div class="textting">
               <h1>
                 Third Info
               </h1>
             
             </div>
             
            </div>
            <div class="half-row">
              <h3>
                blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
                blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
              </h3>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="half-row" style="width:15%;">
             <div class="textting">
               <h1>
                 Third Info
               </h1>
             
             </div>
             
            </div>
            <div class="half-row">
              <h3>
                blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
                blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
              </h3>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="half-row" style="width:15%;">
             <div class="textting">
               <h1>
                 Fourth Info
               </h1>
             
             </div>
             
            </div>
            <div class="half-row">
              <h3>
                blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
                blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
              </h3>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="half-row" style="width:15%;">
             <div class="textting">
               <h1>
                 Fifth Info
               </h1>
             
             </div>
             
            </div>
            <div class="half-row">
              <h3>
                blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
                blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
              </h3>
            </div>
        </div>



    </div>


</body>


<script>


</script>




</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are positioning your diamonds using `position: absolute`. This positions them to the `body` element *unless* you put them in a `div` and style that `div` using `position: relative`. The positioning of the `li` elements in that `div` will then be positioned relative to that `div`. So wrap the `ul` and `li` elements inside a `div`, set a class on that `div` to `posiiton: relative` then that will push the other markup below that div.

I also see that you're using `transform:translate` and pushing the diamonds up so add a `margin-top` to the container `div` to allow the diamonds to be seen. Example below.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  font-family: poppins, sans-serif;
}

.ul-container {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 300px;
}


/*dimonds cover page top*/

.main-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 600px;
  height: 150px;
}

.main-nav li {
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transition: 0.5s;
  margin: -100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0.6;
  border-color: rgb(236, 39, 236);
  border: solid rgb(236, 39, 236)
}

.main-nav li:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*about me button*/

.main-nav li.item1 {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 47px;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px #6531a8;
  text-shadow: 0px 2px 4px #8c31b6;
}

.main-nav li.item2 {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 25%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 47px;
}

.main-nav li.item3 {
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 47px;
}

.main-nav li.item4 {
  top: 100%;
  left: 75%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 47px;
}

.main-nav li.item5 {
  top: 0%;
  left: 100%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 47px;
}

.main-nav li.bg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: scale(1.1);
  ;
}

.title {
  background-color: rgb(192, 183, 183);
  top: 0;
  width: 75px;
  height: 0;
  margin: 70px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: popping, sans-serif;
  font-size: x-large;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: relative;
  left: -40px;
}

.main-nav li.item1 .bg {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.nav-title {
  border-radius: 25%;
  border: solid 2px rgb(236, 39, 236);
  height: 71%;
  width: 386px;
  align-content: center;
  color: white;
  display: inline;
}

.nav-title:nth-child(n + 2) {
  margin-left: -1px;
}


/*border lines for dimonds bottom page */

#container {
  padding: 5px;
  padding-top: 350px;
  /*edit here*/
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}

.row {
  min-height: 50px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 2%;
}

.half-row {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 1%;
  height: 25%;
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid yellow;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.textting {
  color: white;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="ul-container">
  <ul class="main-nav">
    <button onclick="">
      <!--jump to first section box-->
      <!-- first is picked-->
      <li class="item1">
        <div class="bg">
          <div class="title">
            First
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </button>
    <!-- second button is clicked-->
    <button onclick="">
      <!--jump to 2 section box-->
      <li class="item2">
        <div class="bg">
          <div class="title">
            Second
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </button>
    <!--Third box info is clicked-->
    <button onclick="">
      <!--jump to first section box-->
      <li class="item3">
        <div class="bg">
          <div class="title">
            Third
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </button>
    <!--fourth div is cliked-->
    <button onclick="">
      <!--jump to first section box-->
      <li class="item4">
        <div class="bg">
          <div class="title">
            Fourth
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </button>
    <!--fifth is cliked -->
    <button onclick="">
      <!--jump to first section box-->
      <li class="item5">
        <div class="bg">
          <div class="title">
            Fifth
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </button>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="half-row" style="width:15%;">
      <div class="textting">
        <h1>
          First Info
        </h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="half-row">
      <h3>
        blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
      </h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="half-row" style="width:15%;">
      <div class="textting">
        <h1>
          Second Info
        </h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="half-row">
      <h3>
        blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
      </h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="half-row" style="width:15%;">
      <div class="textting">
        <h1>
          Third Info
        </h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="half-row">
      <h3>
        blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
      </h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="half-row" style="width:15%;">
      <div class="textting">
        <h1>
          Third Info
        </h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="half-row">
      <h3>
        blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
      </h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="half-row" style="width:15%;">
      <div class="textting">
        <h1>
          Fourth Info
        </h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="half-row">
      <h3>
        blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
      </h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="half-row" style="width:15%;">
      <div class="textting">
        <h1>
          Fifth Info
        </h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="half-row">
      <h3>
        blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
      </h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```